# how to make isLogin true after login is done?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, angular-event-emitter

I am not being able to get isLogin value boolean value from login.component.ts after the login is completed.

I already tried @output EventEmitter. The problem with EventEmitter is that, it is called in selector of parent component. But in app.component.ts has not any child selector. you can see it in app.component.html

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { SnackbarService } from 'src/app/shared/snackbar.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CommonHttpService } from 'src/app/business-cockpit/services/common-http.service';
import { BusinessDialogComponent } from 'src/app/business-cockpit/business-dialog/business-dialog.component';
import { BranchDialogComponent } from 'src/app/business-cockpit/branch-dialog/branch-dialog.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  @Output() isLogin = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  
  hide = true;
  username: string = "";
  password: string = "";


  constructor(private  CommonHttpService:CommonHttpService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginComponent>,
    private router: Router, private snackBarService: SnackbarService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  login() {
    const payload = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }
    // this.loginService.login(payload).subscribe((response: any) => {
    //   this.dialogRef.close();
    //   this.router.navigateByUrl("/business-home");
    // }
    // )

    this.CommonHttpService
    .create('/public/login', payload)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {

      if ( response.user.businessId == null) {

        this.dialog.open(BusinessDialogComponent,{ disableClose: true });  
   
      }
      this.dialogRef.close();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/business-home');

      this.isLogin.emit(true)
    });

    console.log(this.isLogin)
  
  }



}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="before-Login" *ngIf="!isLogin">
    <app-public-navbar></app-public-navbar>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <h1>Header sample H1</h1>
    <p>this is a test text</p>
</div>


<div class="afterLogin" *ngIf="isLogin">

    <app-business-cockpit></app-business-cockpit>

</div>
```

I want to get isLogin value true after the user get login. If isLogin is true then Ngif render business-cockpit

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './public/login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {


  isLogin = false
  title = 'business-manager-ui';
}
```

Comment: If you want to share information about components without the possiblity to use input and output use a service you inject in both. There you can introduce a behavior subject or if you are using angular 16 a signal to hold this information.

Comment: can you clarify! How to use that

Comment: Do you know how the dependency injection is working in angular? Well, if you define a service injected in root, you can use it in every single component and it is the same instance.  If you there define a signal or a behavior subject you can share information around.  But please notice to secure you app / api very well. This is client side code which can be manipulated easily.